# Official Stack Exchange Test App

Tags: app

This app registration is being used for testing new API features.

Further details will be announced when those features are available.

Comment: *Interesting...* (I guess this is some new super-secret feature?)

Comment: This sounds fun :)

Comment: Is this the **Stack Apps post to write** for the StackExchange API viewer? I've tried to add a comment [through it](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-comment) but it gives me _Applications must have a registered Stack Apps post to write_.

Comment: @systempuntoout no, the API console is not authorized to write (too open to abuse).  It'll get a little cleaner as the beta gets closer to ending, but for now it basically just documents the available parameters on write methods.